# Angular 6 - Observable subscription not working

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

[Edited]

I have tried as best as I could to clean up the question. I have managed to login with the test user and this redirects me to the home component and displays the users name.

I was able to do this because in the Controller I changed the name of the parameters of the equals methods to `John` & `test`:

```
return user.getCname().equals("John") && user.getPassword().equals("test");
```

This brought me to the homepage which should have displayed `Hi John` but instead showed me this:

[image: homepage error]

## Home Component:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    cname: string;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/user';

        const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')
        });

        const options = { headers: headers };
        this.http.post<Observable<Object>>(url, {}, options).
            subscribe(principal => {
                this.cname = principal['name'];
            },
            error => {
                if (error.status === 401) {
                    alert('Unauthorized');
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

## Login Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    model: any = {};


    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', '');
    }

    login() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/login';
        this.http.post<Observable<boolean>>(url, {
            cname: this.model.username,
            password: this.model.password
        }).subscribe(isValid => {
            if (isValid) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('token', btoa(this.model.username + ':' + this.model.password));
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            } else {
                alert('Authentication failed.');
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### ---

I then went to my `BasicAuthConfiguration` and changed the values for "user" and "password" to "John" & "test" like so:

```
auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("John").password("test").roles("USER");
```

I am able to login with that user if I set the strings to be the values from the SQL table. How do I get around not hardcoding in the values?

## Customer controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public boolean login(@RequestBody Customer user) {
        return
          user.getCname().equals("user") && user.getPassword().equals("password");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authToken = request.getHeader("Authorization")
          .substring("Basic".length()).trim();
        return () ->  new String(Base64.getDecoder()
          .decode(authToken)).split(":")[0];
    }
```

## Basic Auth Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicAuthConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .httpBasic().and().cors();
```

}
}

## Error

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the response of the API in the network tab of chrome. Can you please post that?

Comment: ive added that to the post

Comment: `console.log(isValid)` what do you see?

Comment: it says false even though the data for cname and password match whats in the SQL table.

Comment: try printing Customer object to console and see if values are correct or not

Comment: Okay. The problem is not in Angular but in your backend spring.

Comment: I have most of my backend code on the post I linked in this question or here is a link to the github where the source code can be found : https://github.com/conormc93/FinalYearProject

Comment: OK -> @ConorMcGrath, you need to do some debugging on your own, and present the shortest code necessary to be able to reproduce your problem. There is way too much going on in this question for a reasonable person to even want to guess as to what could be the issue.

Comment: i've edited the post to show some of the debugging I have done